# meteor package with coffeescript (and inheritance and strict mode)

Tags: javascript, meteor, coffeescript, package, strict-mode

I'm trying to build a meteor package in strict mode with coffeescript.
The main problem is the use of **share** as described in the [coffeescript meteor package](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/coffeescript). It seems that I misunderstood the explanation in the link because I get the following error:

```
 ReferenceError: __coffeescriptShare is not defined
```

The packaged worked well in javascript. I just put the definition of **NotificationCommon** before the **'use strict'**.

The goal is

- **NotificationCommon**, scope package
- **NotificationClient** and **NotificationServer**: scope file
- **Notification**: export

This is my version with *coffeescript*:

**notification_common.coffee**:

```
'use strict'

class share.NotificationCommon
  constructor: ->
    @collection = new (Meteor.Collection)('notification')

    @SUCCESS = 'success'
    @ERROR = 'error'
    @INFO = 'info'
    @WARNING = 'warning'
```

**notification_client.coffee**:

```
'use strict'

class NotificationClient extends share.NotificationCommon
  constructor = ->
    self = @

    Meteor.subscribe 'user_notif'
    toastr.options = positionClass: 'toast-bottom-full-width'

    @collection.find({}).observe 'added': (notif) ->
      self.notify notif
      return

  notify = (notif) ->
    toastr[notif.type] notif.message, notif.title, notif.options
    @collection.update { _id: notif._id }, $set: notified: true
    return

Notification = new NotificationClient
```

**notification_server.coffee**:

```
'use strict'

class NotificationServer extends share.NotificationCommon
  constructor = ->
    self = @

    @collection.allow update: (userId, doc, fields, modifier) ->
          return doc.userId is userId

    Meteor.publish 'user_notif', ->
      if @userId
        return self.collection.find( userId: @userId, notified: false)
      return

  notify = (user_id, notif) ->
    self = @
    checkType = Match.Where((x) ->
      check x, String
      check x, Match.OneOf('success', 'error', 'info', 'warning')
      true
      )
    check notif,
      type: checkType
      message: String
      title: Match.Optional(String)
      options: Match.Optional(Match.Any)
      context: Match.Optional(Match.Any)
    if user_id isnt null
      if not Meteor.users.findOne(_id: user_id)
        throw new (Meteor.Error)('User id not found.')
      notif.userId = user_id
    notif.notified = false
    self.collection.insert notif
    return

Notification = new NotificationServer
```

and the **package.js**:

```
Package.describe({
  name: 'my:notification',
  version: '0.0.1',
  summary: 'User and system wide notification',
  git: '',
  documentation: 'README.md'
});

Package.onUse(function(api) {
  api.versionsFrom('1.1.0.2');

  api.use(['coffeescript','jquery']);
  api.use('chrismbeckett:toastr');

  api.export('Notification');

  api.addFiles('notification_common.coffee');
  api.addFiles('notification_server.coffee','server');
  api.addFiles('notification_client.coffee','client');

});

Package.onTest(function(api) {
  api.use(['tinytest','coffeescript']);
  api.use('my:notification');
  api.addFiles('notification-tests.js');
});
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to add the package 
[fds:coffeescript-share](https://github.com/foxdog-studios/meteor-coffeescript-share) in **package.js**:

```js
  api.use('fds:coffeescript-share');
```

See the link for an explanation.

It would be helpful if the explanation of the package [coffeescript](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/coffeescript) would describe the problem (related to **use strict**) and inform about the existence of the above-mentioned package.

**EDIT**

Thank you [@jorjordandan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31759640/meteor-package-with-coffeescript-and-inheritance-and-strict-mode#comment51462447_31762158) for your comment. 
I may conclude that at the moment there is no complete solution for combining

- meteor package
- coffeescript
- strict mode

**EDIT 2**

I've analysed deeper the problem and I thing that there is no solution to be found inside the *coffeescript* package.

The problem should be solved by the meteor team in the package building code.
I could imagine a solution as follows. A new instruction is added to the Meteor package API: beside **export** another named something like **scopePackage**.
The variables declared with **scopePackage** will be listed under `/* Package-scope variables */` (in the concatenated js).
But they will be not exported (code under `/* Exports */` in the concatenated js).

Comment: The readme says that package is not for use by other packages. It adds: "fds:coffeescript-share makes the same share object available to everything that uses it. This allows shared objects to leak outside of their package. This is only a problem when fds:coffeescript-share is used by other package."